# Convert a datetime index to sequential numbers for x value of machine leanring

Tags: python, pandas

This seems like a basic question. I want to use the datetime index in a pandas dataframe as the x values of a machine leanring algorithm for a univarte time series comparisons.

I tried to isolate the index and then convert it to a number but i get an error.

```
df=data["Close"]
idx=df.index
df.index.get_loc(idx)


Date
2014-03-31    0.9260
2014-04-01    0.9269
2014-04-02    0.9239
2014-04-03    0.9247
2014-04-04    0.9233
```

## this is what i get when i add your code

```
    2019-04-24 00:00:00                                               0.7097
    2019-04-25 00:00:00                                               0.7015
    2019-04-26 00:00:00                                               0.7018
    2019-04-29 00:00:00                                               0.7044
    x                      (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14...
    Name: Close, Length: 1325, dtype: object

I ne
```

ed a column of 1 to the number of values in my dataframe

Comment: What is expected output, can you add to question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select column `Close` by double `[]` for one column `DataFrame`, so possible add new column:

```
df = data[["Close"]]
df["x"] = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)
print (df)
             Close  x
Date                 
2014-03-31  0.9260  1
2014-04-01  0.9269  2
2014-04-02  0.9239  3
2014-04-03  0.9247  4
2014-04-04  0.9233  5
```

Comment: Cheers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column with value `range(1, len(data) + 1)` as so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}, index=pd.date_range(start="2019-08-01", periods=5))

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
            y
2019-08-01  5
2019-08-02  4
2019-08-03  3
2019-08-04  2
2019-08-05  1

df["x"] = range(1, len(df) + 1)

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
            y  x
2019-08-01  5  1
2019-08-02  4  2
2019-08-03  3  3
2019-08-04  2  4
2019-08-05  1  5
```

Comment: When I add your line it ends up being a row not a column?

Comment: That is weird, can you reproduce it?